# Android phones on armv5 processor?

Tags: android, arm, processor

Is there a way of knowing all the android phones that run armv5 processor?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Android `os.arch()` output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859954/android-os-arch-output-for-arm-mips-x86), at least related.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.getProperty("os.arch")
```

returns a String, for example: "armv5tejl" and "armv6l". I don't know what the "L" stands for - ARM never uses it. If you wanted an actual list of all products sold by all companies which are based on an ARMv5 core, that is another question. I have no idea where to find such a list.

Answer (score 1):

This thread on XDA provides a list of ARM-v5, v6 and v7 devices, might not be exhaustive but should provide base information:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1596800

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this blog post](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/09/read-android-cpu-info.html), a possible solution would be to read the processor information located on the phone like so :

```
   String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
   cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

   Process process = cmd.start();
   InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

   // TODO: Read information and extract the needed information
```