# Android os.arch output for ARM, MIPS, x86?

Tags: android, arm, mips, android-x86

In order to identify the platform of an Android device, it seems that the java system property "os.arch" will suffice:

```
Log.i("mytag", "os.arch: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
```

most ARM devices respond: `os.arch: armv7l`

An x86 emulator responds: `os.arch: i686`

What are the outputs of this for *real* Intel and MIPS devices?

x86 Android device: ??????

mips Android device: ??????

Any other platforms and variants?

EDIT for Google TV:

It looks like Google TV uses 'none' for Build code.

Vizio Co-Star:  os.arch: armv7l  ,  Build.CPU_ABI/Build.CPU_ABI2: none/unknown

Logitech Revue: os.arch: i686 , Build.CPU_ABI/Build.CPU_ABI2: none/unknown

EDIT for clarifying intent:

The goal here is to crowdsource the compilation of a list of *real* devices with their output.  The expected output from AOSP code is interesting, but device manufacturers, like the old Google TV units above, may deviate from supplying the output expected from AOSP code.

Comment: You should probably be using [android.os.Build.CPU_ABI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI) and CPU_ABI2.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 12):

According to what I can find in the Android source tree the `ro.product.cpu.abi` property (which you can access as `CPU_ABI` through the [Build class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI)) should have the following architecture-to-value mapping:

### 32-bit ABIs:

**ARM**: "armeabi-v7a"  (or possibly "armeabi" if it's a really old / low-end device)

**x86**: "x86"

**MIPS**: "mips"

---

### 64-bit ABIs:

**ARM**: "arm64-v8a"

**x86**: "x86_64"

**MIPS**: "mips64"

Comment: Android documentation of supported ABIs: http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa

Answer (score 4):

These values come from a Linux structure.  They can be displayed from a shell by `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. The ARM  defines them in the `arch/arm/mm` directory.  From this directory,

```
grep cpu_arch_name * | grep string | cut -d \, -f2 | sort | uniq
```

- armv4
- armv4t
- armv5t
- armv5te
- armv5tej
- armv6
- armv7

The *arm7l* indicates "little endian" mode, but this is selectable and depends on the kernel.  I would think most ARM kernels will be "little endian", unless it is a network centric product (like an Android router).  This is the same as `uname -m`.  On the x86, it returns "i686" on a PowerPC, it returns "ppc".  I don't have a MIPS system, but my guess is "mips", but it could be the assortment found in [**cpu-probe.c**](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/mips/kernel/cpu-probe.c)

There are over 20 architectures in Linux all with different CPU versions.  The answer is far less for current Android ports.  However, it is possible that any of them can be used in the future.  I think that the ARM is the only one sending a *sub-architechure*.

See also: [`uname()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html), [Wikipedia's *Uname*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname), [Server faults's uname machines](https://serverfault.com/questions/63484/linux-what-are-the-possible-values-returned-by-uname-m-and-uname-p), [OpenJdk mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=openjdk-jdk8-dev&m=135796746534007&w=1)

Comment: This is useful. I'm mainly interested in reports from actual Android devices running on x86 and MIPS, and I agree that BUILD.CPU_ABI may be a better measure.  FYI, on an ARM device (Galaxy Nexus), Build.CPU_ABI / CPU_ABI2 are:  armeabi-v7a / armeabi

Answer (score 0):

This may be help

1. Build.CPU_ABI The name of the instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code.
2. Build.CPU_ABI2 The name of the second instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code.

More Info
[Android Build Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI)