# what's the difference between `uname -a` and `uname -m`

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to know my computer architecture, so i typoe command on my os to check it .It shows that my computer architecture is 'i686' when i type `uname -m`and `arch`.But it show `i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`when i type `uname -a`.I have known that `uname -a` prints  print  all  information and `uname -m` print the machine hardware name. So  why it prints `i386` when i type `uname -a`.And what's the difference between them .

Comment: Whatever the difference is, this question does not belong to Stack Overflow but rather to the [Super User](http://superuser.com/) site or to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: [Something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859954/android-os-arch-output-for-arm-mips-x86).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man uname`:

```
   -a, --all
          print all information [...]

   -m, --machine
          print the machine hardware name

   -p, --processor
          print the processor type or "unknown"

   -i, --hardware-platform
          print the hardware platform or "unknown"
```

So, the triple from the output of `uname -a` correspond to `machine processor hardware`, in that order.

Comment: I have tried to know something from man page but I want to know the detailed. Why it shows `i386 linux`when i type `uname -a` ,but `i686` when i type `uname -m`.

Comment: The part corresponding to `-m` in `-a` *is* `i686`! `i386` is the `hardware platform` (`-i`).